# How to access data in InputStream as String?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to create an android client and java server application using socket programming. I need to retrieve the file send from java server but i dont want to write that content into another file in client side. Instead i want to create a listbox with the contents in the received file. I can find code for write these contents in a file but I dont know how to access the contents as strings.

Here is the code i tried:

**Android client**

```
client=new Socket("10.0.2.2", 7575);
writer=new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
writer.write(mMsg);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
InputStream is=client.getInputStream(); 
bytesread=is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
```

I changed my code as follws but it is not working.

```
 InputStream is=client.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 String value=bf.readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your inputstream into a `BufferedReader`

```
BufferedReader d
          = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

and use [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method.

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputStream is=client.getInputStream(); 
bytesread=is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
// Create a new String out of the bytes read
String data = new String(mybytearray, 0, bytesread, CharSet);
```

OR

Wrap the `InputStream` using `BufferedReader` and read the data line by line (using `readLine()`) in `String` format.

Comment: when i give the above code it give an error that CharSet is not resolved to a type. What i need to give? pls give any suggestion

Comment: @user3243259: Refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html. For now you can pass it as "UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

Using buffered reader is best or you can try the code below:

After the last statement use the `byte[] "mybytearray"` to convert to string as below:

```
if(bytesread > 0)
    String result = new String(mybytearray);
```